# android listview custom row layout manipulate (with Loaders)

Tags: android, listview, android-loadermanager

I have a ListView which has custom row_layout.xml which has 3 TextViews.

to display the data in the listview i use LoaderManager

i want to change all the 3 TextViews background color to red/green/orange according to the value of one of the items.

in order to that i overrided the setViewValue in my adapter (SimpleCursorAdapter)

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int coloumIndex)
            {

                if (coloumIndex == cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLdataHelper.INVITE_STATUS))
                {

                    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invite_Status);
                    InviteStatus status = InviteStatus.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLdataHelper.INVITE_STATUS)));
                    switch(status)
                    {
                        case atProgress:
                        {
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
                            break;
                        }

                        case Completed:
                        {

                            //TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Invite_RequestedDate);
                            //TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invite_Name);
                            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            //tv2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            //tv3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            break;
                        }

                        case Received:
                        {

                            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

this code is working . but it only change one of the item..

in the switch case i tried to get the TextView of the other 2 items and i get NullPointerException

how can i color the other 2 items in my list?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are misinterpreting the 'view' written in the arguments of setViewValue().
I think, you are taking it as if this view represents the whole xml file but that is not true.

For example, suppose we have a xml file which has LinearLayout as a root view and two textviews as its children. Then the method setViewValue() will be called for each textview separately.

And who will decide that on which individual views this method is to be called? Well, all the views mentioned in initialization of SimpleCursorAdapter i.e., "int[] to" of [this constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20android.database.Cursor,%20int%29) for the setViewValue() method. It says, this method **Binds the "Cursor column" defined by the specified index to the "specified view"**.  This columnIndex is the index of column in this cursor which is related to the view.

In your case, it can be done like this:

```
dataAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int coloumIndex)
        {
            // In you case.. this view itself is a textview so you can use it directly.
            boolean output = false;
            switch(view.getId()){
                case R.id.invite_Status:{
                    InviteStatus status = InviteStatus.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLdataHelper.INVITE_STATUS)));
                    // change
                    switch(status){
                            //changes to invite_status textview should be done here.
                            case atProgress:{
                                view.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
                                break;
                            }
                            // and so on
                    }
                    output = true;
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.Invite_RequestedDate:{
                    InviteStatus status = InviteStatus.valueOf(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLdataHelper.INVITE_STATUS)));
                    // change
                    switch(status){
                            //changes to invite_RequestedDate textview should be done here.
                    }
                    output = true;
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.invite_Name:{
                    // similar as above.
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    });
```